# compileReleaseJavaWithJavaC failed for react native modules when building a release build

Tags: android, react-native, annotation-processor

> Task :react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

  > java.io.FileNotFoundException: /workspace/eos-native/node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build/intermediates/annotation_processor_list/release/annotationProcessors.json (No such file or directory)

The error makes sense , and the file is not there, but I have no idea why its not there? It is created when I run a debug version of the app and debug versions of my libraries, react-native-device-info, react-orientation-locker etc..  I've cleaned, gradle synched, rebuilt etc. but when trying to assemble or install a release build I get this error within seconds.  What is causing the Java

Comment: Take a look at the Gradle scripts for that library, and maybe the package.json, and see if there are any discrepancies between the debug and release configurations relating to that file

Comment: one thing that is interesting to note, that react-native-appboy-sdk is able to build a release version but the others throw errors as shown above.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem in an android project (without react) when I added a library module.

After searching for a solution for quite some time, I finally deleted the **.gradle** directory in the project root folder.

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Had this error seeming at random :/ Tried everything, finally removing .gradle folder worked. Thanks.

Comment: I tried clean and cleanBuildCache, but the problem persisted. Completely removing .gradle/ fixed it.

Comment: this solution did not work

Answer (score 0):

update android gradle plugin to 3.3
update gradle to 4.10.3

fixed the issue for me.